# Is there a library in python to accomplish cross platform OS binary installation? Cross platform dependency installation via Python

Tags: python

I often write Jupyter notebooks (python) and since you can execute them in Windows or Linux (and the many flavors thereof), when I have a dependency for the notebook's activity (like let's say the notebook is meant to demo a proof of concept for a Node.js module CVE), well I can execute a command to install that node module cross platform, since Node.js / node package manager works the same on various platforms. But it would be more beginner friendly and convenient if I could also install Node.js for them, with Python.

I could write a bunch of logic to detect the platform and so on, but that would be a lot of work each time. Before I write some re-usable solution myself, I'm just wondering if it's already been done. Or even if there's a good best-practice / trick in python to make it easier.

For example with this code (executed in an ipynb file):

```
# Prereqs: docker-compose, node.js, node package manager

import requests
import os

path = "./open_vas"
exists = os.path.exists(path)
if not exists:
    os.makedirs(path)

r = requests.get('https://greenbone.github.io/docs/latest/_static/docker-compose-22.4.yml')
with open("./open_vas/docker-compose.yml",'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)

!docker-compose -f ./open_vas/docker-compose.yml -p greenbone-community-edition pull
!docker-compose -f ./open_vas/docker-compose.yml -p greenbone-community-edition up -d
!npm i express@4.10.4
```

I'd like a cross platform solution to install those pre-reqs and save the user the time / effort.

Comment: Python is notorious for being difficult to package and install reliably. The root problem is that, either a package has a wheel (binary) built exactly for your environment (Python version, ABI and platform, cf [convention](https://peps.python.org/pep-0427/#file-name-convention)). You could download all of them, then perform an offline install using [`pip install --find-links`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#options).

Comment: @Lenormju that is insightful, thanks, but I'm referring to a challenge slightly more robust, which is non-python cross platform dependency installation. Let's say I want to install Node.js or Docker Compose so that all you need to execute the Jupyter Notebook is, well, Python and Jupyter. And one user is on a flavor of linux with yum and the other just has apt. Maybe another is on Windows. I'd like to install Node.js or Docker compose cross platform. I probably need a lot of boilerplate code to pull this off.

Comment: So you want to implement in Python a way to provide reproducible environment across platforms. This definitely is a very **large and difficult** problem. Some kind of existing solution to that is actually Docker : build an image, distribute it, and different users can run it on their own computer, if they have Docker. But that may not work for low-level differences (CPU/GPU/...).

Comment: @Lenormju Ah yeah, I guess Docker is the only feasible way to do this consistently. It's the defacto reason Docker exists, after all. AFAIK